# codeigntier and file location

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a default installation of codeigniter. in my public_html folder (root) I created js folder. Inside that I have a tinymce (Rich-Text editor). Under that folder there is a tinymce.min.js file. When I type this in the browser, I can't see the content of the file:

> http://mydomain.com/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js

it shows me codeigniter 404 error page. in my .htaccess I have this:

```
# Use PHP5 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

My base url is defined in config.php:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.mydomain.com/';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Index File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Typically this will be your index.php file, unless you've renamed it to
| something else. If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this
| variable so that it is blank.
|
*/
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

What could it be leading to this error? Why can't it locate and display the file content? This is the root-cause of problem in my view.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this condition in your htaccess file

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|js|images|robots\.txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

In config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = '';   #remove index.php
```